# when I should use "on" or "at"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I was at doctor office few days back and there was lady who was trying to come in the office.But couldn't as the door was locked. I told the nurse there that "somebody is on the door" and she replied back saying you mean "somebody is at the door ?".

Which one is correct ?

Comment: I just [answered this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/211599/15299) for _in_ and _on_. The idiom _at the door -- at_ [locates _the door_ on a two-dimensional plane](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/199115/15299) (like _at 25th and Locust_) -- means that someone wants to come in. To say _He is on the door_ is to say that he is arrayed on a two-dimensional object (_the door_), rather like a tiger skin. This is not the image you really want.

Comment: "on the door" lets me think of "the clock on the wall".

Comment: Colloquial for a security guard, who would be said to be 'on the door' i.e. preventing the wrong people from entering. [though for the OP's example, it's 'at', of course]

Answer (score 1):

There are several definitions of On. But On would generally be used if you're a part of something such as "I am on the team." Or sometimes being physically atop of something. "I am standing on the table." At is used when someone is somewhere, a location. "I am at the mall." "I am at the corner of the street."

Comment: -1 There are just so many much better answers to this (kind of) question.

Answer (score 1):

'at the door' is always correct when referring to someone knocking/using the doorbell.

'on the door' is wrong in 99% of the cases. Like someone else said, "on the door" is only correct should you want to express that someone is physically standing on top of the door.

And while [JaththeGod's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/211607) is correct, there are cases where you cannot use logic: "on the phone" for instance. Doesn't mean you're part of something, but it's still used that way.

Answer (score 1):

A bouncer, security guard or doorman is said to be 'on the door', meaning in charge of the admission of those people who are at the door.